# Flutter CupertinoDatePicker shows time backwards (mm:hh instead of hh:mm) when locale is set to 'he' (Hebrew)

Tags: flutter, datetimepicker

When setting locale to 'he' (Hebrew) and using the CupertinoDatePicker, the time is shown backwards, meaning 'mm:hh' instead of 'hh:mm'.
Setting locale to 'en' shows it just right.

Is it a bug or can I control this setting?

Here's a test build method:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter test',
      localizationsDelegates: [
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
      ],
      supportedLocales: [
        const Locale('en', 'US'), // English
        const Locale('he', 'IL'), // Hebrew
      ],
      locale: Locale('he', 'IL'),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: CupertinoDatePicker(
          mode: CupertinoDatePickerMode.time,
          use24hFormat: true,
          onDateTimeChanged: (DateTime date) {
            print('date is ' + date.toString());
          }
        ),
      ), // for debug purposes
    );
  }
```